# I want my heroku bot to log into a txt file

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, txt

I know Heroku has an ephemeral hard drive and I dont want to lose my log file so I uploaded my bot to GitHub as a private repo and linked to Heroku. But it didnt write any thing to log file and it has been working for two days. Can you edit GitHub files during runtime or I need different approach.

```
def log(line):
  file_object = open("log.txt", "a")
  file_object.write(line)
```

Comment: Your code is bundled up and deployed to Heroku, GitHub doesn’t matter anymore when it’s running. You would need the code to write logs and then commit them to GitHub - but that’s a rather flaky way of writing logs. Look into using a logging service - Heroku have some third party ones that are free for low-volume usage.

Comment: File-based logging is an antipattern and will not work as you expect on Heroku. I suggest you read about Heroku's log stream. You can capture its output using an addon or custom log drain and do whatever you want with it, as long as that doesn't require writing to the local disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to edit GitHub files, you need to use the GitHub API (https://docs.github.com/en/rest). There are plenty of python packages that have been written for the GitHub API, so you shouldn’t need to send raw requests. (Bear in mind that this probably isn’t the best way of storing data).